# .closest( selectors [, context]) bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, closest

I have a problem with .closets() in jQuery

On jQuery documentation tell that I can use like it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style></style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul><li></li><li></li></ul>
<script>
  var close = $("li:first").closest(["ul","body"]);
  alert(close.length);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest2

In this part I get information about ul and body, two steps up of li

```
var close = $("li:first").closest(["ul","body"]);
```

But it doesn't work, inside the close don't have anything, it's empty, what I'm doing wrong?
The code from jQuery documentation is wrong too. The example doesn't work.

Comment: **This signature (only!) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.**

Comment: The demo in the jQuery documentation itself does not appear to be working either.

Comment: The demo is using jQuery 1.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to select the closest ul and the closest body, you should instead use `.parents()` and `:first` since the method you are currently trying to use has been removed in recent versions of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/MYjRm/

```
var close = $("li:first").parents("ul:first,body:first");
  $.each(close, function(i){
  $("li").eq(i).html( this.nodeName );
});​
```

`.closest()` by definition can only select 1 element, since you're looking for two, you should use `.parents()` which can select more than 1.

If you simply want to select 1 element, use `.closest()` with a selector that will select that one element. `$("li:first").closest("ul");`

Answer (score 3):

Re-read the docs:

> This signature (only!) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. This method is
>   primarily meant to be used internally or by plugin authors.

**[Example pre-jQuery 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GfNsv/1/)**

**[Example post-jQuery 1.7](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/GfNsv/)**

Comment: Ok but, how can I use it, like get information about 2 steps up? With the new jQuery version ?

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to get?

Comment: 2 parent's up than $("this") like the <body> and the <ul> in this case.
The "@Kevin B" example work good using parents().